# Select cities of airports from one table which is related to the other table with 2 columns: departure and arrival

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having trouble with the selection of needed columns by using SQL. **I need to find from where and to where a passenger has flown.**

I have added a schema diagram and highlighted the needed tables.
[image]

My code is below and it needs some help at the last stage:

```
SELECT f.departure_airport, f.arrival_airport, city
FROM flights f
   JOIN ticket_flights tf on f.flight_id=tf.flight_id
   JOIN tickets t on tf.ticket_no=t.ticket_no
   JOIN airports a on f.departure_airport=a.airport_code OR
 f.arrival_airport=a.airport_code
```

Now I have only 3 columns: departure_airport, arrival_airport, city.

**I need to get a table with 4 columns: departure_airport, arrival_airport, city_departure, city_arrival.**

I would really appreciate your help with the final part of SQL query and explanation of such type of relationship between tables Airports and Flights.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another join to the airports table for the departure airport:

```
SELECT f.departure_airport, f.arrival_airport,  
       a.city as city_arrival,
       d.city as city_departure
FROM flights f 
JOIN ticket_flights tf 
  on f.flight_id=tf.flight_id 
JOIN tickets t 
  on tf.ticket_no=t.ticket_no 
JOIN airports a 
  on f.arrival_airport=a.airport_code 
JOIN airports d 
  on f.departure_airport=d.airport_code 
[...]
```

Comment: There should be a comma after (a.city as city_arrival) but overall it works! Thank you so much!